# Replacing strings in a list using conditionals

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has a column called regional_codes. Now I need to add a new column into the dataframe where the regional codes are replaced by the list of countries that are attributed to that region.

For eg. if the regional_codes contains `['asia']` then I need my new column to have the list of asian countries like `['china','japan','india','bangaldesh'...]`

Currently what I do is that I have created a separate list for each region and I use something like this code

```
asia_list= ['asia','china','japan','india'...]
output_list = []
output_list+= [asia_list for w in regional_codes if w in asia_list]
output_list+= [africa_list for w in regional_codes if w in africa_list]
```

and so on until all the regional lists are exhausted

With the codes that I have provided above, my results are exactly what I need and it is efficient in terms of running time as well. However, I feel like I am doing it in a very long way. Therefore, I am looking for some suggestions that can help me shorten my code.

Comment: I might be wrong, but is `[['asia','china','japan','india'], ['asia','china','japan','india'], ['asia','china','japan','india'], ['asia','china','japan','india']]` really what you want ...? Because this is what `[asia_list for w in regional_codes if w in asia_list]` returns if `asia_list= ['asia','china','japan','india']`

Comment: You *could* do something like `world_dic = {'asia': ['china', 'japan', ...], 'africa': ['morocco', 'algeria', ...]}` then `output_list = [(country_list for _, country_list in world_dic.items() if code in country_list) for code in regional_code]` (untested) which is "more extendable", but I would not recommend it (since it replaces decently clear code by a monstruous one-liner list comprehension).

Comment: @BlueSheepToken actually i use one or two further lines of codes to flatten the list but I was lazy to put them here :D

Comment: @Muzammil123 ok :) But to be honest I have no idea what you are expecting so I have no way to give you clues ! :p

Answer (score 0):

One way I found to do this is to create a DataFrame with all the needed data for your `regional_codes` and the `regional_lists`

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np
# DF is your dataframe
# df is the dataframe containing the association between the regional_code and regional lists 
df = pd.DataFrame({'regional_code': ['asia', 'africa', 'europe'], 'ragional_list': [['China', 'Japan'], ['Morocco', 'Nigeria', 'Ghana'], ['France', 'UK', 'Germany', 'Spain']]})
#   regional_code                 ragional_list
# 0          asia                [China, Japan]
# 1        africa     [Morocco, Nigeria, Ghana]
# 2        europe  [France, UK, Germany, Spain]


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'regional_code': [['asia', 'africa'],['africa', 'europe']], 'ragional_list': [1,2]})
#       regional_code  ragional_list
# 0    [asia, africa]              1
# 1  [africa, europe]              2

df2['list'] = df2.apply(lambda x: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((df.loc[df['regional_code']==i, 'ragional_list'] for i in x.loc['regional_code']))), axis=1)
# In [95]: df2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
# Out[95]: 
#       regional_code  ragional_list                                               list
# 0    [asia, africa]              1        [[China, Japan], [Morocco, Nigeria, Ghana]]
# 1  [africa, europe]              2  [[Morocco, Nigeria, Ghana], [France, UK, Germa...
```

Now we flatten the `df2['list']`

```
df2['list'] = df2['list'].apply(np.concatenate)  
#       regional_code  ragional_list                                               list
# 0    [asia, africa]              1            [China, Japan, Morocco, Nigeria, Ghana]
# 1  [africa, europe]              2  [Morocco, Nigeria, Ghana, France, UK, Germany,...
```

I guess this answers your question?